# Связь между таблицами в Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть клас:

```
 public class Match
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Tour Tour { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateMatch { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Team Home { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Team Guest { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

Где `Team Home`and `Team Guest` другие класс, которые уже существуют в базе,
    при добавлении:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Teams'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Teams'. The duplicate key value is (06f67648-f904-4a4e-8ceb-33c204d8267c). The statement has been terminated.

как сделать не добавление новой команды, а связь с уже существующей?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, как можно два `ForeignKey` добавить

```
public class Match
{
    [Key]
    public int MatchId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("HomeTeam"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GuestTeam"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int GuestTeamId { get; set; }

    public float HomePoints { get; set; }
    public float GuestPoints { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public virtual Team GuestTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: для форматирования кода используйте `Crtl+K`, сниппет используется для оформления Html/JS/CSS кода

Comment: Но у автора же проблема не в этом...